# Sustainsys Saml2 start authentication for ASP.NET Web Forms Example

Tags: asp.net, webforms, sustainsys-saml2

I found the information below to start auth for web forms from Anders Abel. I can't find any actual example code anywhere on how to use the HttpModule to start the auth redirect. Can someone provide some please? I have multiple idps, so I would need a way to specify one.

> You should use the HttpModule with Web forms. To start authentication
> redirect the user to /Saml2/SignIn.
>
> Or protect the entire application with automatic redirection by
> settings in web.config:
>
> Authentication mode Forms with a login url of /Saml2/SignIn Set
> Authorization rules in web.config to disallow anonymous access to all
> pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the code from github...
https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2

and still there but you need to go back a little bit in time to commit
`62552e250cccd8a7663d9ce29b3239eae51ce498`
to get the example